# How to NOT handle View.onClick() and handle View.onLongClick() in the same time?

Tags: java, android, onclick, onlongclicklistener

I need to handle only long click event of the TextView (and show popupmenu on this event). But in case of just simple clicking I should transfer this event to layout hosting this view.

How to achieve this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnLongClickListener, OnClickListener {

TextView mTextView;
RelativeLayout mTopLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
    mTopLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mTopLayout);

    mTextView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    mTopLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, v.getClass().getName() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (v.getId() == R.id.mTextView) {
        ((View) v.getParent()).performClick();
    }
}

...
}
```

In this way we will receive two sequential click events and there will be two standard click sounds in android. Not good.

Is there some ease way of achieving this?

Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mTopLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
Just to add details. If I will not set onClickListener then clcking in TextView is done without any effect and this event is consumed by mTextView (even if clickable and focusable is set to false in xml) and not passed to mTopLayout

Comment: may be GestureDetecter will help here?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally...

Why at all I need to make this onClickListeners use different handlers? Stupid.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, v.getClass().getName() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (v.getId() == R.id.mTextView || v.getId() == R.id.mTopLayout) {
        //do whatever I need
    }
}
```

Really simple.

Answer (score 1):

i am unclear with what you want to do with click only, but android only catters only one click listner at a time either onClick or onLongClick.

Comment: Click only will go on background layout and will do some other action, not related to TextView. So, simple clicks should behave in that way, as there is no this TextView at all, and only long clicks should open context menu for copying its contents to Clipboard - that is a background of all this stuff.

Comment: And just checked, Android caters both `onClick()` AND `onLongClick()` on the same `View`.

Answer (score 1):

Add separate listeners..

```
mTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // do something;
        }
    });

mTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something

        }
    });
```

Comment: In this case Android will consider onClickEvent in mTextView's onClickListener as processed and will issue click sound - which is bad

Answer (score 0):

I just created a demo project. same issue **OnLongClick** it was firing the **OnClick**
also 
but when i changed the return value of `setOnLongClickListener` to `false` 
it started managing these clicks individually.

```
 mbuttton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.View1);

        mbuttton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "single click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Single Click", "Single click");
            }
        });

        mbuttton.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "LONG click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Long Click", "Long click");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I made it happen but if you are asking for explanation oooohhh i am almost giving up then, dont know how these return values are managed

Comment: onLongClickListener returns true. The problem is in short Link :) How to tell Android, that I do not need it at all? :)

Comment: what this will give? onLongClickListener() is not invoked at all on short clicks.

Comment: I made it happen but if you are asking for explanation oooohhh i am almost giving up then, dont know how these return values are managed ..

returning false actually making it happen updated my answer (contains my demo application just created to check it)